# Is there a way to create package-info.java for existing packages in one move in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package-info

I have some legacy packages which doesn't have `package-info.java`. For some reason I need to create `package-info.javas` for them and I found the task really boring because there is no shortcut in eclipse for me to do that. I have to manually use the `New > File` procedure to create the file, then manually type in those package names.

Is there a shortcut in eclipse for such task?

Comment: BTW, in IntelliJ IDEA you can add one through the file → new menu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's counter-intuitive, but Eclipse's "New Java Package" dialog with its option to create a `package-info.java` works for existing packages, too.

Just right-click the existing package, select `New > Package`, and leave everything except the "Create package-info.java" checkbox unchanged.

This will produce a `package-info.java` that's pre-populated with the correct package name and an empty javadoc comment block (possibly with `@author` tags and similar default content depending on your settings). Works even if you don't have an existing file to copy from. Tested with Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: Thank you, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 9):

There is no easy way to do this as far as I know, at least "the right way."

What you can do as a shortcut is right-click `package-info.java` and click "Copy." Then you can use the keyboard shortcut to paste the `package-info.java` in any package. Eclipse automatically changes the `package org.whatever.pkgname;` command to match the package you paste the java file into.